# Show continuity of product metric (Carothers Chapter 5 Exercise 34)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

> Show that $d$ is continuous on $M \times M$, where $M \times M$ is supplied with "the" product metric (referring to any one of $d_1$, $d_2$, or $d_\infty$). This says that $d$ is *jointly* continuous, that is, continuous as a function of two variables. [Hint: if $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$, show that $d(x_n, y_n) \to d(x, y)$]

*I don't completely understand this question. Using the hint provided by Carothers, I came up with the following proof:*

> Choose a point $q = (x, y)\in M \times M$ along with convergent sequences $x_n, y_n \in M$ where $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$. Setting $N$ sufficiently high so that $|x_n - x|$ and $|y_n - y|$ are less than $ \epsilon/2$ for all $n\geq N$, we find that the distance between $q$ and $q_n = (x_n, y_n)$ is $$d^p(q_n, q) = (|x_n - x|^p + |y_n - y|^p)^{1/p} < \epsilon \text{ for all }n \geq N\\ \text{or equivalently, that }d(x_n, y_n) \to d(x, y)$$

*Where I'm having trouble is in understanding how this maps onto the definition of continuity using pre-images, i.e., $B_\delta^d(x) \subset f^{-1}(B_\epsilon^\rho(f(x))$.*

*If the distance function is the map  $f: (M\times M, d) \to ([0, \infty), d)$, are we simply defining $f(q^i) = d(q^i, q)$ and then saying that points in the $\delta < \epsilon$ open neighborhood of $q$ in $M\times M$ are in the preimage of the open interval $[0, \epsilon)$ of  $[0, \infty)?$*

**Edit:** Just to clarify, I believe I understand the relationship between the sequential and topological definitions of continuity, but was confused over whether the question is asking me to establish the continuity of $d^p$ using the metric itself, i.e., whether I'm being asked to show that $d^p(B_\delta^{d_p}(q)) \subset B_\epsilon^{d_p}(d^p(q))$.

Comment: Do you not have a theorem relating continuity to convergent sequences in metric spaces?

Comment: I do. In this particular case, I was just having trouble in establishing the continuity of the distance metric, since it seemed like we relied on the distance metric itself to establish its own continuity in this space!